# sql server stored procedure single quotes

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am totally confused with this procedure.please correct my mistakes in quotes.

```
create procedure queryingsfor 
  @Tabname nvarchar(250),
  @colname nvarchar(250),
  @opname nvarchar(290),
  @valuesname nvarchar(239) 
as
begin
  set NOCOUNT on;
  declare @sql varchar(4000)
  set @sql='select * from' +@Tabname+ 'where' +@colname+''''+@opname+''''+ ''''+@valuesname+''''
  exec(@sql)
end
exec queryingsfor 'education','eduCurrentStudy','=','DME'
```

I'm only getting:

> Error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'fromeducationwhereeduCurrentStudy'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to add some spaces in there

```
set @sql='select * from ' +@Tabname+ ' where ' 
           +@colname+''''+@opname+''''+ ''''+@valuesname+''''
```

The correct statement would be something like

```
set @sql='select * from ' +@Tabname+ ' where '
           +@colname + @opname+ ''''+@valuesname+''''
```

Or

even better

```
set @sql='select * from [' +@Tabname+ '] where 
           [' +@colname + ']' + @opname+ ''''+@valuesname+''''
```

Comment: @astander.Thank You so much.It works fine.Stack overflow is really good.

Comment: @astander use `from ' + quotename(@Tabname) +' ` instead of manually putting quotes. It handles fully qualified table names etc.

Comment: The reason for using quotename() is that `set @TabName = 'sysobjects]; drop table Users;select 1 from [sysobjects'` will drop the table in your version, but not when using quotename()

Answer (score 1):

To protect you from [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) you should do like this instead.

```
alter procedure queryingsfor 
  @Tabname nvarchar(250),
  @colname nvarchar(250),
  @opname nvarchar(4),
  @valuesname nvarchar(239) 
as
begin
  set NOCOUNT on;
  declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
  set @sql = 'select * from '+quotename(@Tabname)+ ' where ' +quotename(@colname)+@opname+'@valuesname'
  exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@valuesname nvarchar(239)', @valuesname
end
```